# First attempt at a Blackjack game

Tags: java, beginner, game, playing-cards

I am not happy with this code as I am sure there are better ways to do what I'm trying to achieve. I'm a beginner and I've used what I know to date to complete this.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SeventySix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //52 Cards, Aces = 11, Picture cards = 10, Ace's cannot be reduced to 1.
        int[] newCard = {2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11};

        //Shuffle. Once per game.
        shuffleArray(newCard);

        //Start BlackJack.
        System.out.println("Welcome to BlackJack!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You get a " + newCard[0] + " and a " + newCard[1] + ".");
        int playerTotal = newCard[0] + newCard[1];
        System.out.println("Your total is " + playerTotal + ".");
        System.out.println();

        //Player can get blackjack/bust in the 1st deal. - awaiting betting system (enhanced bets for blackjack in first round)
        if (playerTotal == 21){
            System.out.println("Blackjack, you win.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (playerTotal > 21){
            System.out.println("Bust, You lose.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // Dealer cards
        System.out.println("The dealer has a " + newCard[2] + " showing, and a hidden card.");
        int dealerTotal = newCard[2] + newCard[3];
        if (dealerTotal > 21){     //Dealer bust check.
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Dealers total is " + dealerTotal + ".");
            System.out.println("Dealer is bust, you win!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (dealerTotal == 21){    //Dealer blackjack check.
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Dealer reveals his second card: " + newCard[3] + ".");
            System.out.println("Dealers total is " + dealerTotal + ".");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Dealer has BlackJack, you lose.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("His total is hidden.");
        System.out.println();


        // Hit or Stay for player.
        System.out.print("Would you like to \"hit\" or \"stay\"? ");
        String hitStay = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println();

        //cc = card count
        int cc = 4; 
        if (hitStay.equalsIgnoreCase("hit")){
            // While loop to ensure different cards & multiple "hits".
            while (playerTotal < 21 && hitStay.equalsIgnoreCase("hit")){
                if (hitStay.equalsIgnoreCase("hit")){
                    System.out.println("You drew a " + newCard[cc] + ".");
                    playerTotal = playerTotal + newCard[cc];
                    System.out.println("Your total is " + playerTotal + ".");
                    System.out.println();
                    cc++;        //Adds 1 to ensure next card is different.
                    // Bust & Blackjack check.
                    if (playerTotal > 21){
                        System.out.println("You are bust, You lose.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    if (playerTotal == 21){
                        System.out.println("Blackjack, you win.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    System.out.print("Would you like to \"hit\" or \"stay\"? ");
                    hitStay = keyboard.next();
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }        
        }

        // Dealers turn, only if Round 1 didn't end in bust/blackjack.
        keyboard.close();
        System.out.println("Ok dealers turn.");
        System.out.println("His hidden card was a " + newCard[3] + "."); // reveal hidden from round one.

        cc++; // Pretty sure its not needed.
        while (dealerTotal < 16){ // Dealer will stay on 16+ and hit if below.
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Dealer chooses to hit.");
            System.out.println("He draws a " + newCard[cc] + ".");
            cc++;
            dealerTotal = dealerTotal + newCard[cc];
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("His total is " + dealerTotal);
            // bust check - no need for blackjack check due to final win sequence
            if (dealerTotal > 21){
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Dealer is bust, YOU WIN!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            // stay condition.
            if (dealerTotal < 21 && dealerTotal > 16){
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Dealer Stays.");
            }
        }

        // final win sequence.
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Dealer total is " + dealerTotal);
        System.out.println("Your total is " + playerTotal);
        System.out.println();

        if (dealerTotal > playerTotal){
            System.out.println("Dealer wins.");
        } 
        if (dealerTotal == playerTotal){
            System.out.println("You both draw.");
        }
        if (dealerTotal < playerTotal){
            System.out.println("You win.");
        }
    }

    static void shuffleArray(int[] deckCards){

        /**
         * This code is obtained from the internet and is not my own though process
         * I need to understand it before I will be happy using it.
         * I'll have a try at explaining this, please correct me if I suckarino.
         * deckCards is a placeholder for the array I chose to use.
         * i = the length of the array which is 52, -1 would be 51.
         * i will be greater than 0 until the i-- completely loops it down to 0.
         * index is a random number between 1 & 52.
         * a is a random number in the array.
         * deckCards[i] is replaced with a; 
         * essentially shuffling 1 card in the array, this happens 51 times?
         */

        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = deckCards.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Swap
            int a = deckCards[index];
            deckCards[index] = deckCards[i];
            deckCards[i] = a;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to keep the comments understandable to some degree.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should make your entire application more Object Oriented. 
A good place to start would be to move the deck of cards and associated functions into other classes.

Here's an implementation of a deck stolen from a [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15942601/334274). Notice there's also a `Card` object.

```
public class DeckOfCards {
  private Card cards[];

  public DeckOfCards() {
    this.cards = new Card[52];
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        Card card = new Card(...); //Instantiate a Card
        this.cards[i] = card; //Adding card to the Deck
    }
  }
}
```

Also think about using `enums` for suit and a method of tracking the card value. Searching Google for Cark rank patterns will help with this.

You have a lot of multiline print statements that could probably be joined together;

```
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Dealer total is " + dealerTotal);
System.out.println("Your total is " + playerTotal);
System.out.println();
```

Could be;

```
System.out.println(
  String.format("\nDealer total is %s \nYour total is %s \n", dealerTotal, playerTotal)
);
```

To save on complexity, these should be `else if`s instead;

```
if (dealerTotal > playerTotal){
    System.out.println("Dealer wins.");
} 
else if (dealerTotal == playerTotal){
    System.out.println("You both draw.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("You win.");
}
```

Finally, your code is not very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). You need more of your functionality in separate methods to prevent you repeating yourself. A good example of this is that you have multiple win sequences. Your win/lose conditions should result in a win/lose method being called which executes the appropriate sequence.

Also Blackjack is a repetitious game, turn two is identical to turn one, your code just repeats the same operations a second time. Again this should be moved into methods.

Answer (score 11):

I'd just like to point out that though the cards would be better represented as objects instead of `int`s, and the program organization and flow is a bit muddled, your choice of shuffling algorithm is excellent.

The [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is a simple and unbiased way to randomize the order of the elements of an array, and you have a textbook implementation of it.  Even if you didn't write the code yourself, I think you should get credit for picking the right code to copy.

---

**Edit:** Since you asked about the validity of the comment in `shuffleArray()`…

This is what you wrote, ignoring the initial noise:

> - `deckCards` is a placeholder for the array I chose to use.
> - `i` = the length of the array which is 52, -1 would be 51.
> - `i` will be greater than 0 until the `i--` completely loops it down to 0.
> - `index` is a random number between 1 & 52.
> - `a` is a random number in the array.
> - `deckCards[i]` is replaced with `a`;
>
> essentially shuffling 1 card in the array, this happens 51 times?

Your vocabulary is slightly off, and the remarks about `i` going down to 0 and `index` being between 1 and 52 are inaccurate.

> - `deckCards` is a **reference to the input array. This function shuffles its elements in place.**
> - `i` **is initially the index of the last element of the array.**
> - `i` **iterates down to 1.**
> - `index` is a random number between **0 and i, inclusive.**
> - `a` is a random **element of** the array.
> - `deckCards[i]` is **swapped** with `a`;
>
> essentially shuffling 1 card in the array, this happens 51 times?

However, that is an uninsightful, mechanical description of the code.  A better comment would be:

> For each element of the array (except the first), starting from the end, pick any previous element (or itself) with uniform probability, and swap them.
>
> This technique is unbiased.  For example, consider what happens during the first loop when shuffling a 52-card deck.  Every card in the deck is equally likely to take the position of `deckCards[51]`.  With the last element `deckCards[51]` thus fairly selected, repeat the process — randomly draw from the remaining 51-card deck to fill its last element `deckCards[50]`, and so on for the entire deck.

Comment: Thank you for this, I did a fair amount of research to see what shuffling method would be good. Just an additional question, my comments explaining the fisher-yates method is that correct? I don't like using code I don't understand.

Comment: Indeed, your comment has some problems. I've added a critique of the comment in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

There is a small mistake in your code:

Aces are **only** 11, but not 1. This means the player (or the dealer) could bust with just the two cards they're dealt.
Assuming they only had Aces, then it would be a bust with this code. I would add a check to see if the player is busting, but that one of the cards was dealt as an Ace. Possibly even creating a boolean, `PlayerHasAce`.

Pseudocode:

```
If they bust, and PlayerHasAce is TRUE;
    minus 10 from the total;
    are they still busting without additional aces? 
    No? Good! They can continue playing.
```

You would just need to make sure the boolean is set only ONCE per Ace though, and not repeated during the same hand.

Comment: your pseudo code isn't complete,  if the player has 2 Aces (22) we subtract 10 (12) then gets a ten (22) it should now be (12), they will bust,  you need a more complex process for this.

Comment: @Can if it is only checked once it won't change both aces to have a value of 1,  it will only check one of the aces.  in this case it should change the second ace to a value of one when the ten card is drawn. it needs to be checked more than once.

Comment: Sorry @Malachi, what I meant was that it only does it once per Ace... I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 10):

In addition to creating an object for Deck, an object for a player's hands and the dealer hand will also be useful. In Blackjack a player may take different actions depending on the first two cards dealt, split or double.  The player may also take different actions depending on the dealer's up card -- take insurance if it is an ace.

With all that in mind, the basic objects of the game might be:

`Deck`: holds available cards

`DealersHand`: holds cards removed from deck and dealt to dealer. One of the first two cards is the up card.

`List[Player]`: all the players

`List[PlayerHands]`: each Player has a list of `PlayerHands`

All hand objects should be able to calculate their score

Finally you may consider a Game object that can deal hands, evaluate the winners of each round, keep score and display the results.